# Загрузка фотографий в конец списка, начиная с конкретного id

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Хочу реализовать подгрузку более ранних фотографий из вк при пролистывании RecyclerView до конца.

Интересует именно то, как в таком случае формировать запрос. Если я хочу, исходя из того, какое фото было последним в списке, подгружать фотографии, идущие до него в альбоме.

Обычный запрос для фотографий из открытого альбома выглядит так:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-альбом&album_id=wall&rev=1&count=10&access_token=ключ_доступа&v=5.101
```

Была идея отправлять запрос на максимальное допустимое количество фотографий, которое можно получить от вк за раз - 1000, а потом уже вытаскивать из модели полученные элементы по мере прокрутки RecyclerView, но, как мне кажется, это не совсем удачное решение, на случай если пользователь захочет получить ещё более ранние фото, прокрутив всю тысячу фотографий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте атрибут offset. Позволяет определить место, с которого начнется отсчет фотографий. То есть смещаем базовую индексацию с 0 на нужное нам количество.

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-альбом&album_id=wall&rev=1&count=10&access_token=ключ_доступа&v=5.101&offset=10.
```

Получаем фотографии с 11 по 20.